# Saber cuando hago clic unicamente sobre un objeto || pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy haciendo un juego de tipo tablero-fichas y quiero saber si hay una forma de hacer la siguiente condición:

Primero, tengo por ejemplo tres objetos:

1. Base.
2. Ficha blanca.
3. Ficha negra.

En el juego las fichas **"blancas"** y **"negras"** se pueden posicionar sobre "base".

```
if "hago clic sobre base y no hay ninguna ficha sobre base":
    se cumple esto
elif "hago clic sobre base y hay una ficha sobre ella":
    no se cumple
```

No sé si me di a entender bien, pero bueno. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor pon el código con lo que tienes y lo que has intentado. Así podremos ayudarte trabajando sobre algo. Si tu pregunta es si se puede hacer, la respuesta es Sí.

Comment: hola. gracias por responder. si pongo el codigo seria muy largo ya que hay muchas cosas que dependen de otras y seria dificil enterder una fraccion del codigo sin analizar el resto. pero solo lo que quiero saber es como hacer para que si tengo una condicion que diga que si hago clic sobre un objeto que no sea, por ejemplo el objeto "base" retornar falso.